# How to access the button on the form?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I have a form that appears when you start the plugin.How do I properly apply to the button on the form, so that when you click on the button performed "function".

```
import sys,os
import win32api
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
import ctypes
from PyQt4 import uic

class HelloWorld:
   def __init__(self, iface):  
      self.iface = iface
      self.canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

   def initGui(self):  
      pushButton=QPushButton("pushButton")
      self.action = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/"), "&HelloWorld", self.iface.mainWindow())
      self.action.setWhatsThis("Configuration for test plugin")
      self.action.setStatusTip("This is status tip")
      QObject.connect(self.action, SIGNAL("activated()"), self.hello_world)      
      QObject.connect(pushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.function)

      self.iface.addPluginToMenu("HelloWorld", self.action)   

   def unload(self):    
      self.iface.removePluginMenu("HelloWorld",self.action)
      self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)

   def function(self):
      QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(), QCoreApplication.translate('HelloWorld', "HelloWorld"), QCoreApplication.translate('HelloWorld', "HelloWorld"))
      return

   def hello_world(self):      
      path = os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )
      self.optionsDialog = uic.loadUi(os.path.join(path,"untitled.ui"))
      self.optionsDialog.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   pass
```

Comment: Your pushButton variable isn't on the form.  You need to add it to your untitled.ui using QtDesigner

Comment: I have it there has already been added. it did so. the only question is how to appeal to a button on this form?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the button on the form you can just do:

```
  self.optionsDialog = uic.loadUi(os.path.join(path,"untitled.ui"))
  self.optionsDialog.pushButton.toggled.connect(self.function)
  self.optionsDialog.show()
```

`pushButton` is the objectName of the QPushButton.

Comment: This part of the code should be in the "def hello_world(self)"?

Comment: yes inside hello_world()

Comment: In "def initGui(self):" No need to change anything ?

Comment: well you don't need `pushButton=QPushButton("pushButton")` or `QObject.connect(pushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.function)` in there.

Comment: and that, instead, I need to use?

Comment: Anywhere I need to specify the name of a button? Otherwise he will understand exactly which button to work? when I press the button, nothing happens

Comment: You don't use anything.  You are connecting the button on the form with `self.optionsDialog.pushButton.toggled.connect(self.function)` in hello_world()

Comment: but for some reason he does not see the function

Comment: do you have a button on your form with the name pushButton

Comment: can I have something wrong with the function? when I press the button, nothing happens